# Keypressed Event behaviour in Windows 10 vs xp, 7, and 8

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hey We are having some problems with keypressed events in windows 10
looks like if a textbox has a keypressed event , and you continue to press the keyboard, all other events are blocked.
There is a small delay from last keypress to the block realeses 500milisec - 1 sec.

There is a small delay from last keypress where click events are blocked, 
this block lasts for about 500-1000 milliseconds

On XP-8 this seems to work different.

Anyone having a suggestion to a workaround

What have we tried. 
- Other .net frameworks (3.5 - 4.6.2)
- WPF app same scenario

Video of The Problem:
https://youtu.be/nMIhK46YH3E

A simple sample app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyPressTestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("U Pressed Me u know the btn"); 
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add("U Pressed key " + e.KeyChar );

            //No effect
            //Application.DoEvents();
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No repro. Behaves the same on Windows 10 as on Windows 7 (the button clicks as soon as you click it). The mouse did jerk and was difficult to move on Windows 10 though, which is because the setting to hide the cursor while typing was activated.

Comment: well not in our test, if u rapidly type on the keyboard and at the same time try to click the button, we experience that the click dont get registered...